# Isotope filtering no longer working

Tags: filtering, jquery-isotope

I have just noticed a problem on a website I am working on that uses isotope filtering. The filtering worked fine until recently but has suddenly (or so it seems) stopped working: http://www.hancockstevenson.com/

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Thanks, S

Comment: Hi Sam - I think this is is out of scope for stackoverflow. Hopefully others will recommend the right location.

Comment: Thanks. I'll continue trying to fix it and see what happens. S

Comment: There is no problem with filtering that I see when using the site just now. Filters are working. The only issue is modernizer is not loading with a 404. More info is needed. What browser is it happening in? Did you clear your cache? Except for not posting any code, this is certainly in the scope of Stackoverflow, @micster. Why is it not?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Macsupport. I thought there might be a more specialist graphics group or web application that could help Sam.

Comment: Thanks both. I went back to square one and adjusted some of the coding which is why it's working now. But it was weird that it just packed up. Thanks again for your time.